# Annotation by condition

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models:

```
class City(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()

class VisitedCity(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want to make a queryset with annotated fields `visited` boolean type:

- if this city in visitedcity model and `user=self.request.user` => True
- if not => False

```
`City.objects.annotate(
    ... something ...
)`
```

I tried to use annotate() like this one, but it is not work:

```
queryset_visited = VisitedCity.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
queryset_all = City.objects.annotate(
    visited=Case(
        When(title__in=queryset_visited, then=Value(True)),
        default=Value(False)
    )
)
```

Could you please help me with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier might be an [**`Exists`** subquery <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.db.models import Exists

City.objects.annotate(
    visited=Exists(VisitedCity.objects.filter(city_id=OuterRef('pk'), user=user))
)
```

The `City` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.visited` that will be `True` for cities where for the *`user`* there is a `VisitedCity` object, and `False` otherwise.